# How can you prevent objects of the same type form being added to a list at the same time

Tags: c#

So I have this code where it only allows a debuff to be applied when it hasn't been added yet, but the problem is if the code is called at the same time (projectile that adds the debuff hits at the same frame) then the debuff is added twice.

```
public void AddDebuff(Debuff debuff)
{
    if(!debuffs.Exists(x => x.GetType() == debuff.GetType())) // prevents same type of debuffs stacking
    {
        //Debuffs are first added to newDebuffs
        newDebuffs.Add(debuff);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `!debuffs.Exists(x => x.GetType() == debuff.GetType())` what exactly is this for? I am assuming your list is a `List<Debuff>` and if that's the case, the types are always going to be the same.

Comment: They have different classes FireDebuff, Poison Debuff, etc inheriting from a superclass called Debuff..


I'm following a tutorial on coding a game and this is what they wrote, and have tried to see other videos if they fixed it, but they haven't, so I'm asking here.


I think it mostly works because the same type of debuffs don't get applied twice when they are hitting at different times.

Comment: Can you switch to a dictionary of debuffs as the key and a bool value of isApplied?

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it by adding another condition to the if statement:

There are no more unintended behavior as far as I could tell.

```
public void AddDebuff(Debuff debuff)
{
    
    
    if(!debuffs.Exists(x => x.GetType() == debuff.GetType()) && !newDebuffs.Exists(x => x.GetType() == debuff.GetType())) // prevents same type of debuffs stacking
    {
        //Debuffs are first added to newDebuffs
        newDebuffs.Add(debuff);
    }

    
}
```

The problem was that it was only checking if the debuff already existed on the list that holds the current debuffs, but isn't checking if the debuff already existed on the list of the debuffs to be added.

thus when the list of debuffs to be added is moved to the list holding the current debuffs, then it transports multiple instances of the same debuff.